# Use C# EF objects in AngularJS code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am currently working on an angularjs application with entity framework. I am facing a situation which I am sure is very common and everyone must have faced it.
I have c# entity classes generated by EF and I want to use those in my angularjs code. To be precise, I have angularjs forms which map to those EF classes. The EF classes have FK relationships and also also one-to-many relationships between them.

I want to know if there is a way to correctly represent the EF classes along with their FK relationship in AngularJS which would then be mapped to UI?

I searched on google and I can see people suggesting to use factories in such scenarios, but I am not sure if that is the correct approach to follow and if it will handle complex scenarios which i mentioned above.

Can anyone please advice on this issue like what is the industry standard for such scenarios and how everyone does it?

I am sure I am missing something

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Angular is a frontend framework and should be treated as a layer that could be independent of the backend.

The Angular way of doing what you want is to have Angular services which will make get or put requests to your C#-EF endpoints to do whatever operations you may need.

For example if you have the `Customer` class in C#, you should have an action that returns all the Customers (e.g. `http://example.com/Customers`) as a JSON object, and then in Angular you make a call to this action and build an Angular model and deal with it within Angular.

Simultaneously, if you want to save data, you would just make a put request to your edit customer URL (e.g. `http://example.com/Customer/102319`) with whatever changed fields you have.

All the EF stuff including FK, many-many relationships, validations, etc.. you have to deal with within the C# world, although you can (and probably should) do it as well within the Angular world.

Comment: This is one approach to do it. I mean create collect the data from angular UI in scope objects as individual objects and then pass them to another layer which would then read properties from this json and create real C# objects for further processing. However my concern is this, I have class E with 50+ props, of which one is an array of A, and A itself is another class. So E can have multiple A. So collecting them individually and then trying to put them together in a C# layer would be quite tedious. So I am wondering, how developers are handling such complex scenarios.